# Анимация + изменение угла программно

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - задаю угол поворота объекта на мышь, через update в скрипте.
При этом, если в анимации участвует rotation этого объекта, то изменить угол через код нельзя.
Кто с таким сталкивался - есть ли решения/аналоги, как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменять угол поворота не в *update()*, а в *LateUpdate()*

Comment: Спасибо, правда перестала проигрываться анимация, добавил условие - разделил, теперь когда надо используется анимация, а когда надо - программно.